Coordinate-free calculations in bra-ket notation
I'm interested if bra-ket notation can be used without having to introduce a basis or coordinates in calculations and proofs.
For example, could the notation, if need be, extended with some exterior algebra or geometric algebra to be able to prove things like that the trace operator is symmetric when acting on linear operators?
Or could it be used to show that a reversion of the composition of linear operators is the composition of reversed operators?
Edit:
So the main question is, how can I prove the symmetry of the trace operator with bra-ket notation without basis decomposition and are there any other interesting proofs or tricks to use bra-ket notation in coordinate-free proofs?

"I'm interested in..." OK, but do you have a specific question? A bra is a vector, so it doesn't need to be broken down into a basis, just like how $\vec r$ doesn't need to be broken down as $x\hat x+y\hat y + z\hat z$.

Please distill this into one answerable question.

But usually this notation uses breaking up vectors into basis elements , I find it instructive to find a more abstract way , to get more insight into  general properties

I suppose the most satisfying answer to this question lies in the fact that many proofs can be written by expanding a vector in some basis, which can be left abstract until an actual number is needed. By showing identities in some arbitrary abstract basis, you have shown them for every particular choice.


I'm interested if bra-ket notation can be used without having to introduce a basis or coordinates in calculations and proofs.

If you are asking if it can be used without a basis, yes, it can.
There are so many different potential "calculations and proofs" one could consider. I will give you just one example:

Proof that a normalized state remains normalized over time (for a system described by a conservative time-independent Hamiltonian $H$).
Starting from:
$$
1 = \langle\psi(0)|\psi(0)\rangle
$$
and
$$
|\psi(t)\rangle = e^{-iHt}|\psi(0)\rangle
$$
we have:
$$
\langle\psi(t)|\psi(t)\rangle = \langle\psi(0)|e^{+iHt}e^{-iHt}|\psi(0)\rangle
$$
$$
=\langle\psi(0)|e^{+i(H-H)t}|\psi(0)\rangle
$$
$$
=\langle\psi(0)|1|\psi(0)\rangle =\langle\psi(0)|\psi(0)\rangle=1
$$
QED.

That was a proof and I didn't break the ket vector into a basis.

Can you prove that Tr ( A B)= Tr(B,A) ?
